# RXJS Observable - How to call next from outside of the Observable's constructor

Tags: rxjs, observable, subject-observer

I am building a service which exposes an Observable. In this service I receive external function calls which should trigger a next call on the Observable so that various consumers get the subscribe event. During Observer constructor I can call next and everything works great, but how can I access this outside of the constructor so that external triggers can fire next calls?

```
private myObservable$: Observable<any>;
```

During service init I do

```
this.myObservable$ = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next("initial message");
}
```

Then in other methods of the same service I want to be able to execute something like

```
this.myObservable$.observer.next("next message");
```

The above obviously doesn't work, but how can I accomplish this goal?

I'm assuming I'm missing something basic since there must be a way to emit further messages outside of the Observable's initial constructor

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should create a [`Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) for that

```
this.myObservable$ = new Subject();
```

And then you can call at any point:

```
this.myObservable$.next(...);
```

Or use subscribe:

```
this.myObservable$.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: This is pure `rxjs` - it has nothing to do with `angular`.

Comment: Note: Only subscriptions setup *before* calling `next` will receive new values. If you want to allow subscriptions created *afterwards* use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: that is the best way to trigger anything from any point through service in angular.

Comment: Relevant because what @olsn said https://imgflip.com/i/6i16c0

Answer (score 13):

Actually `Subject` is used for both **publisher and subscriber**, and here I think you need only to publish your value, so simply use Observable.

By using observable, assign Subscriber to class level variable and then use it, like below code

```
subscriber: Subscriber<boolean>;

public observe(): Observable<boolean> {

    return new Observable<boolean>(subs => {
      this.subscriber = subs;
    });
  }

public callNext() {

    if (this.subscriber) {
      this.subscriber.next();
      this.subscriber.complete();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Duh. I was trying to go the other way by passing the Subscriber into the constructor. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways:

1. Make myObservable$ public:

   ```
   public myObservable$: Observable;
   ```
2. Encapsulate the observable in a subject stream, and provide a helper to call next:

   ```
   export class TestService {
     public myObservable$: Observable;
     private _myObservableSubject: Subject;

     constructor() {
       this._myObservableSubject = new Subject();
       this.myObservable$ = this._myObservableSubject.asObservable();
     }

     public NextMessage(message?: string): void {
       this._myObservableSubject.next(message);  
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Boyan, the second looks like it'd work but I'm going with olsn's answer above, seems much more concise.

Comment: Sure, we are talking about the same thing. I got my answer from reading the Angular 2 docs. Specifically this section, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Subject extends Observable, so you don't need this wrapper. Just use Subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, the subject can only have one subscriber if i'm not wrong, not the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

**Observable**: You have to call the next() function from inside the constructor and only one time you can subscribe

```
message = new Observable((observer)=>{
   observer.next(9);
})
     
this.messsage.subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(res)
})

output: 9
```

**Subject:** You have to call next() function from outside the constructor and multiple times you can subscribe.
The subject does not store any initial value before subscribe.

```
messsage = new Subject()
this.messsage.next(3)
this.messsage.subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(' A '+res)
})
this.messsage.next(4)
this.messsage.next(5)
this.messsage.subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(' B '+res)
})
this.messsage.next(6)

output: 
A 4
A 5
A 6
B 6
```

**BehaviorSubject:** You have to call next() function from outside the constructor and multiple times you can subscribe.
The BehaviorSubject does store only one initial value before subscribe.

```
messsage = new BehaviorSubject ()
this.messsage.next(3)
this.messsage.subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(' A '+res)
})
this.messsage.next(4)
this.messsage.next(5)
this.messsage.subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(' B '+res)
})
this.messsage.next(6)
        
output: 
A 3
A 4
A 5
B 5
A 6
B 6
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up combining a couple of things:

- [olsn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859206/2072165), which nicely demonstrates `Subject`'s ease of use
- [Ravi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941683/2072165), which  correctly points out that we only want an `Observable` exposed
- a more functional approach, because `this` and `Class` give me the shivers
- TypeScript typings for generic use

```js
const createObservableWithNext = <T>(): {
  observable: Observable<T>;
  next: (value: T) => void;
} => {
  const subject = new Subject<T>();
  const observable = subject.asObservable();

  const next = (value: T) => subject.next(value);

  return {
    observable,
    next,
  };
};
```