# How do I use RXJS fromEvent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I'm trying to log the click event on a button in react:

```
const InputBox = () => {
  const clicky = fromEvent(
    document.getElementById('clickMe'),
    'click'
  ).subscribe(clickety => console.log({ clickety }));

  return (
    <button id="clickMe" type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};
```

I get the following error 'Invalid event target'

[image]

The setup seems to be fine. If I replace `document.getElementById('clickMe')` with `document` then it logs the clicks. But that logs any click in the document and I just want the clicks on the button in question.

I tried using a ref instead...

```
const InputBox = () => {
  const buttonEl = React.useRef(null);

  const clicky = fromEvent(buttonEl.current, 'click').subscribe(clickety =>
    console.log({ clickety })
  );

  return (
    <button ref={buttonEl} type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};
```

...but then I get the same 'Invalid event target' error.

Can someone help me understand why this is an invalid event target and how to fix this so that I can use fromEvent in react.

---

**Update**

The problem was that I did not register the observable when mounting the react components.

If you do this, you must also unmount the component when unmount.

This works for me now.

```
const InputBox = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const click$ = fromEvent(
      document.getElementById('clickMe'),
      'click'
    ).subscribe(clickety => console.log({ clickety }));
    return () => click$.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <button id="clickMe" type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: is the button on the DOM yet when you are registering?

Comment: Register the listener in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap it in `useEffect()` that's when the dom is ready

```js
const InputBox = () => {
  const buttonEl = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const clicky = fromEvent(buttonEl.current, 'click').subscribe(clickety =>
      console.log({ clickety })
    );

    return () => clicky.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <button ref={buttonEl} type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: This worked thank you.

Don't need to use refs, works with Id selector.

For anyone else following this, you only need to register onMount, so keep your dependancy array empty, rather than mounting on every render.

```const InputBox = () => {
  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      fromEvent(document.getElementById('clickMe'), 'click').subscribe(
        clickety => console.log({ clickety })
      ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <button id="clickMe" type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};```

Comment: ...and also dont forget to unsubscribe 
```
const InputBox = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const click$ = fromEvent(
      document.getElementById('clickMe'),
      'click'
    ).subscribe(clickety => console.log({ clickety }));
    return () => click$.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <button id="clickMe" type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: U can also use subject

Comment: I don't want to use a subject because that forces you to mess with the internals of your observable and handle your own errors, I would prefer an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a couple of assumptions, hoping to present a more generic solution:

- there's nothing special about a `MouseEvent`. We're trying to have an `Observable` of a certain type, owned by a component, and a way to update it.
- using the `Observable` is a concern that should be separate from creating it, so it can be passed on to other components, combined with other observables, etc.
- using `ref`s to attach functionality to buttons is both confusing (since highly non-standard) and not very flexible (what happens if you want to pass that handler somewhere else?)

I'm combining two things in the snippet:

- a `createObservableWithNext` function I described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72442680/2072165). It returns an `Observable`, and a `next` function to update it.
- [`useObservable`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useObservable.md) from the wonderful [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) package. Basically handles subscribing and unsubscribing to observables.

```
const FancyButton = () => {
  const { observable, next } = React.useRef(
    createObservableWithNext<MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>>()
  ).current;

  const latestClick = useObservable(observable);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (latestClick) {
      console.log(`clicked at ${latestClick.pageX} ${latestClick.pageY}`);
    }
  }, [latestClick]);

  return (
      <button onClick={next}>
        Next click
      </button>
  )
};
```